What happened to Obi-wan's lightsaber?
In Star Wars Episode IV we see Vader seemingly kill Obi-wan Kenobi. His saber drops onto his cloak.
Light sabers are considered significant artefacts. Do we know if Kenobi's saber survived the destruction of the Death Star? Did Vader take it?

Short answer is that we don't know. It's not seen again in canon. It appears in various of the legends novels
